# vsftpd: local users are pam users

Tags: permissions, pam, vsftpd

I'm a bit confused about the difference regarding `vsftpd` configuration between local users and virtual users. From the point of view of vsftpd, it doesn't know if a user is a local user or a virtual user, isn't? `vsftpd` just connect to the PAM module set in `pam_service_name`, and if the credentials are correct according to PAM, the login is accepted.

So, why does `vsftpd` documentation makes a difference between them?

For instance, I have got a personalized PAM module that takes login credentials from a database that doesn't use system local (`/etc/passwd`) users, and consequently, I cannot log using any system account, even when `local_enable` is set to `YES` in my documentation.

This confusion is what makes me not fully understand the purpose of `virtual_user_local_privs`. Under which circunstances does `vsftpd` treats a logged user as local or virtual? Does PAM notifies it to `vsftpd` in some way or what? O is there something that I've completely misunderstood?

Are this configuration options, maybe, still present because of legacy reasons?

All of this confusion comes from `vsftp` not providing actual documentation, but just a *reference*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference I was looking for is extracted from one of the `vsftpd` configuration examples in [this](https://github.com/dagwieers/vsftpd/tree/master/EXAMPLE/VIRTUAL_USERS) forked github repo:

> guest_enable=YES
>
> guest_username=virtual
>
> The guest_enable is very important - it activates virtual users! And
>   guest_username says that all virtual users are mapped to the real user
>   "virtual" that we set up above.

So local users are just any user that can be logged-in according to the configured PAM service, and virtual users are local (PAM) users that acts (after being logged-in) as a same actual local (`/etc/passwd`) user. I guess that you can change your `guest_username` on a per-user basis to identify "virtual ftp user groups".

When you personalize your PAM service to create non-system users (a custom list of usernames and passwords that doesn't exists in `/etc/passwd`), `vsftpd` cannot work properly since these users don't really exists in the system, so permissions cannot be checked when uploading or reading directories or files.

So you need a system user acting on behalf of them. That's where `guest_enable` comes into play: every logged user will act as `guest_username`, that must exists as `/etc/passwd` user.

Answer (score 0):

It is all about the permissions.
All files and directories in Linux have a standard set of access permissions. These access permissions control who can access what files, and provides a fundamental level of security to the files and directories in a system.
 The main difference between virtual and local users is that 
local users own their home dirs
Virtual users by default have same as anonymous user permissions.

Comment: But what about `virtual_use_local_privs=[YES|NO]`?